# mp4 video will only play sound in flash cs4

Tags: flash, video, mp4

I'm using a flvplayback component in flash cs4.  The sound from the mp4 video plays fine, but the video doesn't play.  I don't know how to check the specific encoding of the mp4.  I'm publishing to flash player 10 at 24fps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To see what codecs your video uses, you could try playing it in a media player application, like mplayer or Media Player Classic and seeing what that has to say about it...

Comment: This is the format I'm getting from quicktime.  MPEG-4 Video, 352 x 288, Millions
AAC, 2 channels, 44100 Hz

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening the movie in iMovie and re-exporting to h.264.  Video played fine after that.